# How to create a CRUD repository when the ids of the entities are of different types (string/int)?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework

I'm pretty new to REST apis and I'm wondering what the best way would be to create a CRUD repository that handles entities with Ids/primary keys of different types: Car with int, Person with string and Address that consists of two different strings (address and zip code). I have created an IRepository

```
public interface IRepository<EntityBase>
    {
        Task<PayoutResult> Insert(EntityBase entity);
        bool EntityExists(EntityBase entity);
    }
```

And made all the models implement EntityBase, but I'm not sure what BaseEntity should look like when they all have three different id types?

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem, a recommended way is to accept it. Otherwise explain what is missing or what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend having inteface `IEntity` like this:

```
public interface IEntity<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

All entities should implement this interface and then you can have `IRepository` like this:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TKey> where TEntity : IEntity<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    (...)
    Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(TKey id);
    void Insert(TEntity entity);
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using generics will get you started.  `TId` specifies the type of id.

```
public class EntityBase<TId>
{
    public TId Id {get; set;}
}

public interface IRepository<TId>
{
    Task<PayoutResult> Insert(EntityBase<TId> entity);
    bool EntityExists(EntityBase<TId> entity);
}
```

Personally I hate generic repository.  Why?  Its a slippery slope.  I feel it is a bad design choice.  We have an application with this all over the place and it is a nightmare to maintain.  Generic repository does not follow the Interface [Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) either.

[Starter for 10](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern/)